# How to "onclick="location.href=''" for html button, for user login, only after validating credentials?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a login page for a web app.
How do I only allow onclick="" of a button once the username and password have been validated?

Below is what I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Customer Login</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="ch-cn">
<script>

    function validate() {
        var uname = document.getElementById("uname");
        var upass = document.getElementById("upass");
        if(uname.value == ""){
            alert("username can't be null");
            return false;
        }

        else if(upass.value ==""){
            alert("password can't be null");
            return false;
        }
        else
            return true;
    }

</script>
</head>
<body>
    This is the Customer login page.
    <br>
    <form method="post" action="custlogin">
        user SSN:<input type="text" id="uname" name="userSSN"><br>
        <br> password:<input type="password" id="upass" name="pwd"><br>
        <br>
        <button type="submit" value="submit" onclick="return validate();">submit</button>
        <button type="reset" value="reset">reset</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Where are you storing the info for what valid usernames and passwords are?
A database?

I am attempting to help, but I am no expert.

To my understanding would need to test the values of the inputs against the value of what is already saved in your Database.

something like

have the form fields with ids userName , passWord

```
if {
userName == howeverYouReferenceAusernameindb
&& passWord == @tablename.columnName 
{
login code here
}
else { "please put valid creds"
}
}
```